# SSL certificate - Use Client certificate installed on server for local testing - Mutual authentication

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, mutual-authentication

I have been working with web services connecting to URLs provided by different clients and so far it has all been done using one-way authentication. Now I'm asked to enable 2-way (mutual) authentication for one of the clients. I did a lot of research and reading but still confused about a lot of things.

I could test successfully on my local machine following instructions from various different articles. But the problem is now to deploy it in production.

Here's what I did for testing: I created a test Web service Host and assigned it a self-signed certificate and created a client to test this. After this I created a client certificate using makecert and verified that this is installed via MMC. I then modified my Host app to only allow clients with certificate and tested from client to see the connection refused due to not providing the client certificate. Then I modified the bindings in the client application to include the certificate name and I was able to connect to the Host successfully. So this completes local hosting.

Now the real problem. The tech team is going to create a certificate in "cert store" on the server. And I need to test again to make sure everything works as expected. We have a few different developers who all want to test on their machines on their local code. Can we all use the same certificate somehow? I don't think we would be allowed to import the certificate but what suggestions could I give them so all of us can use the same certificate?

I'm also confused about issues like difference between windows certificate and IIS certificate. What advantages would the IIS certificate provide?

Thanks for help!

Edit: Could one of the differences between installing on IIS be  so that the hosted sites be accessed via SSL connection? This would mean we don't really need to install on IIS if it's just a client certificate. Is this correct?